# Creating loop for __main__

Tags: python, loops, methods, program-entry-point, args

I am new to Python, and I want your advice on something.

I have a script that runs one input value at a time, and I want it to be able to run a whole list of such values without me typing the values one at a time. I have a hunch that a "for loop" is needed for the main method listed below. The value is "gene_name", so effectively, i want to feed in a list of "gene_names" that the script can run through nicely.

Hope I phrased the question correctly, thanks! The chunk in question seems to be

**def get_probes_from_genes(gene_names)**

```
   import json
   import urllib2
   import os
   import pandas as pd

   api_url = "http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.json"

   def get_probes_from_genes(gene_names):
       if not isinstance(gene_names,list):
           gene_names = [gene_names]
       #in case there are white spaces in gene names
       gene_names = ["'%s'"%gene_name for gene_name in gene_names]**

       api_query = "?criteria=model::Probe"
       api_query= ",rma::criteria,[probe_type$eq'DNA']"
       api_query= ",products[abbreviation$eq'HumanMA']"
       api_query= ",gene[acronym$eq%s]"%(','.join(gene_names))
       api_query= ",rma::options[only$eq'probes.id','name']"

       data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(api_url api_query))

       d = {probe['id']: probe['name'] for probe in data['msg']}

       if not d:
           raise Exception("Could not find any probes for %s gene. Check " \
           "http://help.brain-    map.org/download/attachments/2818165/HBA_ISH_GeneList.pdf?    version=1&modificationDate=1348783035873 " \
           "for list of available genes."%gene_name)

       return d

   def get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(probe_ids):
       if not isinstance(probe_ids,list):
           probe_ids = [probe_ids]
       #in case there are white spaces in gene names
       probe_ids = ["'%s'"%probe_id for probe_id in probe_ids]

       api_query = "?    criteria=service::human_microarray_expression[probes$in%s]"%    (','.join(probe_ids))
       data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(api_url api_query))

       expression_values = [[float(expression_value) for expression_value in     data["msg"]["probes"][i]["expression_level"]] for i in range(len(probe_ids))]
       well_ids = [sample["sample"]["well"] for sample in data["msg"]    ["samples"]]
       donor_names = [sample["donor"]["name"] for sample in data["msg"]    ["samples"]]
       well_coordinates = [sample["sample"]["mri"] for sample in data["msg"]    ["samples"]]

       return expression_values, well_ids, well_coordinates, donor_names

   def get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids):
       package_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
       frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(package_directory, "data",     "corrected_mni_coordinates.csv"), header=0, index_col=0)

       return list(frame.ix[well_ids].itertuples(index=False))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes("SLC6A2")
       expression_values, well_ids, well_coordinates, donor_names =     get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(probes_dict.keys())
       print get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to create a file with Gene names, then read content of the file and call your function in the loop.  Here is an example below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  with open(r"/tmp/genes.txt","r") as f:
      for line in f.readlines():
          probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(line.strip())
          expression_values, well_ids, well_coordinates, donor_names =     get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(probes_dict.keys())
          print get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)
```

Comment: Hey Kozyarchuk, do I put this at the front of the whole chunk of code above? And can I substitute "/tmp/genes.txt" with a "genes.csv" file? Does it work the same way? I found this and i think i should work with example 3: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

whoa, first things first.  Python ain't Java, so do yourself a favor and use a nice """xxx\nyyy""" string, with triple quotes to multiline.

```
 api_query = """?criteria=model::Probe"
             ,rma::criteria,[probe_type$eq'DNA']
             ...
             """
```

or something like that.  you will get white spaces as typed, so you may need to adjust.

If, like suggested, you opt to loop on the call to your function through a file, you will need to either try/except your data-not-found exception or you will need to handle missing data without throwing an exception.  I would opt for returning an empty result myself and letting the caller worry about what to do with it.

If you do opt for raise-ing an Exception, create your own, rather than using a generic exception.  That way your code can catch your expected Exception first.

```
class MyNoDataFoundException(Exception):
    pass

#replace your current raise code with...
if not d:
    raise MyNoDataFoundException(your message here)
```

clarification about catching exceptions, using the accepted answer as a starting point:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(r"/tmp/genes.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():

            #keep track of your input data
            search_data = line.strip()
            try:
                probes_dict = get_probes_from_genes(search_data)
            except MyNoDataFoundException, e:
                #and do whatever you feel you need to do here...
                print "bummer about search_data:%s:\nexception:%s" % (search_data, e)

            expression_values, well_ids, well_coordinates, donor_names =     get_expression_values_from_probe_ids(probes_dict.keys())
            print get_mni_coordinates_from_wells(well_ids)
```

Comment: never mind the bit about the list comprehension, I learned something about building a dictionary from a list instead.  removing.

Comment: Thank you so so much man. I wish i could upvote but i don't have enough rep. May I ask, which line is the one that catches the "no data found" condition? Like if there is a blank space in the .csv file, how do I specify the code to catch this?(apologies if you already typed it above)

Comment: you can always upvote later, when you have the rep ;-)

Comment: Hey @JL Peyret , quick question. What does

"except MyNoDataFoundException, e:
                #and do whatever you feel you need to do here..."

mean?

Like what do i put in 'e' and what do you mean by that # comment? Thanks!

Comment: well, just do what you feel is appropriate for your use.  you catch the exception, you can ignore it or you can write code that does something about the fact that your query didn't return any data.  it's your call - all i am saying is that you can't very well have code that throws expected exceptions - (remember your own exception?), in a loop.  first exception, if unhandled, will terminate the loop.